# How can I move Steam's download folder?

Tags: partitioning, steam

By default, Steam downloads games to the home directory.

On my laptop, my home partition's size is only 15GB; therefore, I'd like Steam to download its games to my Data partition instead, which is much larger.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the folder to the data partition and create a symlink in its old place pointing to the new location. Something like this:

```
mv ~/Steam /mnt/Data/Steam
ln -s /mnt/Data/Steam ~/Steam
```

In Steam's case, there are a few extra files that you should move:

```
cd ~/.local/share
mv Steam/ /mnt/Data/Local-Steam
ln -s /mnt/Data/Local-Steam Steam
```

Comment: This approach has one issue: if the data partition is not mounted on startup (I don't always want it mounted) Steam thinks it's not yet installed and yells about it. Searching a way to disable it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/261718/how-to-disable-steam-autostart-check

Comment: ~/Steam doesn't exist

Comment: Don't Work for me

Answer (score 3):

You can choose another drive directly in Steam. 
But than you have to choose this drive at every Download.

To change the default Download folder, i don't think symlink is the best way.

Just quit Steam (important!) and move the entire Steam folder to another location

> mv ~/.local/share/Steam /new/path

and start Steam again. It says something like "can't find Steam, did you move it?" and than you can choose the new folder location.