# How to install apps to another drive?

Tags: hard-drive, steam

I have a SSD 80 gigs disk which I want to use for Ubuntu 12.10 installation and some programs like Libre Office and Firefox, but the new Steam Linux and games would fill up my SSD quickly. How can I install apps on second 2TB HDD? I read few answers but I don't exactly understand them.

Comment: Does this question solve your problem - http://askubuntu.com/questions/240903/how-can-i-move-steams-download-folder/240904#240904 ? "How do I install apps..." and "How do I install Steam games to another drive" are two completely different questions.

Comment: @Sergey, it helps me but not at all. Anyway thanks ;)

Comment: Be very careful when moving the Steam directory: https://github.com/valvesoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3671