# How to disable Steam check autostarting on every user login?

Tags: steam, autostart

I moved Steam folder to another partition that's not mounted at startup using a symlink: [How can I move Steam's download folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240903/how-can-i-move-steams-download-folder)

Now after every login it thinks it's not yet installed. I checked the package files and there are no XDG autostart. Any suggestion how it even gets launched?
Nothing in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, `~/.config/autostart` and in `systemsettings`.

`Steam->Settings->Interface->Run Steam when my computer starts` **not** checked.

[image]

P.S. I'm on KDE and I don't want to automount the partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it in `/var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/steam-install-notify`.

Notice: it doesn't belong to any package.

Comment: Discussion: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864960986988367270/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to keep Steam from starting when a user logs into the computer? I did that on my machine by opening Steam's settings and unchecking the startup option (Steam->Settings->Interface->Run Steam when my computer starts), although I hadn't moved it like you did and I don't use KDE.

Comment: *Run Steam when my computer starts* is not selected. However, it just asked me if I moved the steam folder and I pointed it to the new location. Now I'll try to relogin.

Comment: No, it's still whining.

Comment: I've added the screenshot.