# How can I mount my partition with executive permissions using the launcher icons?

Tags: partitioning, mount, launcher, steam, executable

I'm trying to install steam games onto my Data partition (NTFS formatted since I use that partition as a bridge for the few times I have to use windows).

I do not want it in my home folder since it is starting to get a bit full (I only have 16 gb of space left)

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240903/how-can-i-move-steams-download-folder) but apparently that doesn't work anymore.

I tried setting the library folder on the Data partition but I just get the response: "New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions."

I usually mount my Data partition using the launcher mount option unity brings with it (just click on the drive on the side bar). I don't really want to change that.

So how can I mount my drives with executive permissions using the launcher icons??

Comment: Never mind I just made a keyboard shortcut with gksudo of the mount with exec command

Comment: For those of you interested in the command I used for the keyboard shortcut its: `gksudo "sudo mount -t ntfs -o defaults /dev/disk/by-label/Data /mnt/Data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it using the following command:

`sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,defaults,exec /dev/disk/by-label/Data /mnt/Data`

and setting it to a keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance if I misunderstood your case, I do not play games so I have no experience with steam.

But if your question **how can I mount my drives with executive permissions using the launcher icons?** describes completely what you need, then one of the possible solutions to this can be changing permissions on the mountpoint after the drive has been mounted. At least in Ubuntu 14.04 these permissions as well as ownership of the mountpoint are remembered by the system.

So, for instance, you have a drive and want to mount it via unity launcher. Then you should:

1. mount it as usual
2. change permissions of the mountpoint: `chmod 755 mountpoint;` (it may require root rights)

After this whenever you mount your drive via the same launcher the drive will be mounted with the remembered permissions and owner.

**As muru pointed, this will not work in case one uses NTFS filesystem**

Comment: This does not apply to NTFS or FAT filesystems. You have to explicitly state their permissions using mount options or in fstab.

Comment: @muru, I did not consider this case, sorry, but nevertheless I will to leave this answer in order to be helpful to someone who uses ext4 or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I fixed it 8 months ago using the following command: `sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,defaults,exec /dev/disk/by-label/Data /mnt/Data` and setting it to a shortcut

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden actually you should post the answer to your own question in such situation.