# Partition mounting with 750 and not 755?

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions

I mount an NTFS drive with the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/karl
```

However it's mounting with permissions `750` and not `755`. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/520990/130518

I was mounting a NTFS and the permissions need to be set explicitly when mounting.