# How to install Steam directly to flash drive?

Tags: software-installation, steam

I'm using a HP Chromebook 14 and I'm running ChromeOS and Ubuntu at same time and I have a 32 GB flash drive.

I'm trying to figure out how to install steam directly to the flash drive but it doesn't ask me where to install it and it ends up on my laptops hard drive. Is there a way in terminal?

Comment: Does it matter where the Steam client ends up? You can always set where Steam downloads things to, and the client itself is not that big.

Comment: Well previously i had the steam client on my laptop hard drive and i install games on the usb but if i end up restarting computer the game will disappear then when i try to add a library folder or whatever it wont let me add where i installed the game so yea if i can get the Steam client on my usb this would be alot easier.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/240903/how-can-i-move-steams-download-folder

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux) You can download the steam tarball from [here](http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.tar.gz)

Download this, put it on your flash drive (I'll use `/media/user/flash/` for where you downloaded it)

Via terminal do

```
cd /media/user/flash #or put in whatever location you actually downloaded it to
tar -xf steam_latest.tar.gz
cd steam
chmod +x steam
./steam
```

This should bring steam up for you, according to their documentaion.

Note that this doesn't 'install' it, but gives you an executable script that you can run from the flash drive. Not sure what implications this might have

Answer (score 1):

If I did understand you correctly then using symlinks that point to the external drive should be the solution you are looking for.

> **Note:** If you already have an existing `.steam` and `.local/share/Steam` folder, then copy it to the external drive before running the commands. You should use a Linux filesystem like EXT4 for the external drive, no FAT or NTFS.

Create a symlink for the `.steam` and `.local` folder in your home directory:

```
mkdir /media/$USER/$your_external_drive/.steam
mkdir -p /media/$USER/$your_external_drive/.local/share/Steam
ln -s /media/$USER/$your_external_drive/.steam .steam
ln -s /media/$USER/$your_external_drive/.local/share/Steam .local/share/Steam
```

That's it, when you want to run Steam you just connect the drive, mount it from the launcher and start Steam. I use symlinks for moving larger folders (Steam, VirtualBox…) from my SSD home partition to another internal HDD and I haven't noticed any issues. There should be no difference between internal drives or external drives unless the drive is easily ejected accidentally (loose plug or too bulky to move the laptop abround while the drive is mounted) or the flash drive isn't able to carry the I/O load (like some cheap micro SD cards or very tiny USB flash drives).

Comment: The reason i need it on my flash drive is because when i restart my laptop the game from the library in steam disappears and it wont let me add the library folder that i downloaded the game in.

Comment: So wait i have to download steam to my hard drive first? then do this?

Comment: @RyanWilson No, either you create the symlinks before installing steam or you copy existing content over to the external drive.

Comment: ok and 1 more question where it says '/media/$USER/$your_external_drive/.steam'  Would i put media/removable/UNTITLED   since thats where my flash drive is

Comment: @RyanWilson `/media/removable/UNTITLED/.steam` in that case, but try to set it up in a way that you not accidentally mount another drive to the same location (I recommend labeling the drive/filesystem appropriately, e.g. "HPC14SteamRyan"), the default behavior on my 14.04 installation is to mount external drives to `/media/$USER` but it can also be `/run/media/$USER` (Fedora) or anything else, depending on your type of installation (chroot or normal), distribution or desktop environment.

Comment: had to get on my phone when I go to askubuntu.com it transfer me but I typed the first command then I typed the second and got mkdir: cannot create directory '/media/removable/UNTITLED/.local/share/Steam' : No such file or directory

Comment: @RyanWilson sorry command fixed (-p creates parent directories)

Comment: Thx ill try this but something happened to my Ubuntu looks like ill have to start over

Comment: i reinstalled ubuntu but should i update to 14.04? before doing this

Comment: @RyanWilson Sorry for the late reply. I don't know if you're running a real install like ChrUbuntu or crouton, but updating to the latest LTS should be fine.